# Computing a value from an XPathNavigator

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, xpathnavigator, xpathnodeiterator

I am trying to write a function for my XSL Transform.

Basically within the function I have a `System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator` and I want to get the value of an XPath when applied to each of the nodes within that iterator.

In this instance the XPath is `concat(name(.) , "_", string(.))` but it could actually be anything.

This is throwing an XPathException: "Expression must evaluate to a node-set."
Which kind of makes some sense

I suspect I'm going to be told this is not a valid XPath but is some other xml/xsl related functionality however, consider that in XSL I can do this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(name(.) , "_", string(.))"/>
```

And that is what I'm after - but within the function.

I'm using C# but VB answers are acceptable.

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator Nodes = whatever;
string KeySelector="concat(name(.), '_', string(.))";
while (Nodes.MoveNext())
{
    System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator xpnValue = Nodes.Current.SelectSingleNode(KeySelector);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the `Evaluate` method and not `SelectSingleNode`. And the result of your XPath is not an `XPathNavigator`, it is an XPath `String` respectively a .NET `System.String` or a C# `string`.

Comment: Thanks. I looked for an Evaluate function but I didn't find it. I guess I was just being blind!

What will Evaluate do if it encounters a XPath that actually is a nodeset? e.g. "Some/Sub/Node"

Comment: The return type of `Evaluate` is `Object`, in case of an XPath expression selecting nodes you will get an `XPathNodeIterator`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c16b7x8.aspx.